# Edit Squirrel shortcuts

Tags: client, squirrel-sql

Someone knows if there is a way to edit keyboard shortcuts in sQuirrel? Some of them have conflicts with the SO ones. This question comes from an old "windowser" and new "linuxer".

I would rather not change the SO shorcuts.

Comment: Just FYI, you shouldn't mix `squirrel-sql` and `squirrel` tags, since the latter is a scripting language. I was confused by your question until I saw the tag for SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a shortcut menu here:

[image]

Hope that helps anybody that has this problem in future.